# SQL: Casting a Float field to NVARCHAR

Tags: sql, sql-server, delphi

I have a table with one float field:

```
CREATE TABLE IMPORTES (IMPORTE FLOAT)
```

Then I run these instructions:

```
INSERT INTO IMPORTES (IMPORTE) VALUES (15226.25)

INSERT INTO IMPORTES (IMPORTE) VALUES (9999.25)

INSERT INTO IMPORTES (IMPORTE) VALUES (5226.25)
```

When I execute `SELECT CAST(IMPORTE AS NVARCHAR(40))`, the biggest value gets rounded so that `15226.25` becomes `15226.3`. Why is that? How can I make the Cast but still get the same value?

Comment: That isn't enough information.  You need to provide what you've tried, what behavior you're seeing, and what you expect to see.

Comment: Done! I think now it's clear.

Comment: Thank you for your edit, @plionut. You might want to add (explicitly) that it is `15226.25` that gets rounded, and -- more importantly -- that it gets rounded to `15226.3`, if I recall your screenshot correctly. Also, I suspect it might be important (or even *very* important) what database you are using. Is it PostgreSQL? IBM DB2? Microsoft SQL? Oracle? MySQL?

Comment: I just edited the question. It's Microsoft SQL. I don't know why, but all the values bigger than 10.000 get round. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: @plionut: Thank you. I have voted to reopen your question. (I don't know MSSQL, but perhaps, by default, the number of significant digits is limited to 6.)

Comment: Use the numeric() type not float if you want decimal numbers without exponents.

Answer (score 2):

According to the documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev15.query%3FappId%3DDev15IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(CAST_TSQL);k(sql13.swb.tsqlresults.f1);k(sql13.swb.tsqlquery.f1);k(MiscellaneousFilesProject);k(DevLang-TSQL)%26rd%3Dtrue&view=sql-server-ver15) for `CAST` and `CONVERT`, for `float` and `real` expressions, the `style` argument to `CONVERT` defaults to `0`, which returns a maximum of 6 digits. Apparently `CAST` is actually calling `CONVERT` with this default value "under the hood", so to speak. The only way you are going to get consistent results is if you change the data type of `IMPORTE` to `numeric(18,2)`, for instance, if you always know that you will only have 2 decimal places.